# After creating cargo I am facing some problems on running this cargo

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am facing this problem on running the Cargo using command (Cargo run) in VS code terminal. My PC is 32 bit.

I also tried to run and compile the main.rs file separately using this commands but the same error arises on compiling.

```
error: process didn't exit successfully: `rustc -vV` (exit code: 1) --- stderr
error: 'rustc.exe' is not installed for the toolchain 'stable-i686-pc-windows-msvc'
To install, run `rustup component add rustc --toolchain stable-i686-pc-windows-msvc`
```

I just need to compile and run this file and get the desire output.

Comment: Try this: [install rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install)

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, you have to install a 32-bit version of Rust (you probably have the recommended 64-bit version already). In a terminal (cmd.exe), run:

```
rustup target add i686-pc-windows-msvc
```